# minSdkVersion not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am following all the instructions I could find and did what seems like the right thing to do and set `compileSdkVersion 23`, `targetSdkVersion 23` and `minSdkVersion 15` to support older versions of Android.

But a beta tester reported that it would not install on his phone because it said his version of Android is incompatible. But he is running Lollipop 5.1.1, which is API 22. So why isn't it working? Here is my gradle config (and my local dependencies are configured likewise).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'config'
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
            storeFile file('/home/xxxxx/android.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'tabcomputing.tcwallpaper'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.1.3"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
   productFlavors {
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // local libraries
    compile project(':library.clock')
    compile project(':library.color')
    compile project(':library.paper')
    // android libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest version of Android Studio and updating to `compileSdkVersion 25`:

Change these lines in your Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

Comment: @Swordsman It is out, I just put it in my app and re-uploaded to app store.

Comment: its is released few day back now the latest one is api 25

Comment: @trans try to set your library to the latest version many times that also cause error

Comment: Well, I updated to the lastest version of Android Studio and changed my versions to 25, rebuilt and upload new APK. Took me a while to get the app to finally push out to Google Play, but it's up and..... NOPE. Same problem. My beta tester just reported it is still saying his phone isn't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the answer is that my beta tester's phone does not support live wallpapers. It's a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime -- a very basic phone. The odd thing is some other wallpaper apps do install, but I think they must be working around the lack of the live wallpaper API somehow, perhaps they are just clever animated gifs. I am not sure. I'll have to look into it more. If anyone else knows, please tell.